# Storybook and Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm getting this error in a React project using another storybook project with typescript inside the company.

In `npm start`, I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@myCompany/ui-components-library'. '/Users/pablo/Documents/git-projects/forward-admin-tools/node_modules/@myCompany/ui-components-library/dist/bundle.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/myCompany__ui-components-library` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@myCompany/ui-components-library';`
```

The problem is that I am using the first components from there.

When I try to install them, I'm getting this other error:

```
 ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fmyCompany__ui-components-library - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/myCompany__ui-components-library@*' is not in the npm registry.
```

Do I forget anything?

Please, I need some help with that.

The project has already been deployed to https://npmjs.com

Kind regards!

Comment: Perhaps your company is using a private package via npm you don't have access to?

Comment: Yes, they are. But I could download the packages of **@myCompany/ui-components-library** without problem. The issue is when I need to install the types because I'm using typescript. Btw, I have developed the storybook project. Maybe, I forgot to do something.

Comment: I mean have you installed the types? Are they in a separate package maybe?

Comment: I have no idea. Inside src folder I have one for all the components.

Comment: Inside `src` folder I have the `components` folder for all my components and the other one whose name is `types` where I have a file `images.d.ts.` The error is that it asks me the images.d.ts types? How can I install them?

Comment: in my project, I have added the definition of `declare module "@myCompany/ui-components-library";` and I can continue with this error and it works. But I am not sure if it's correct this solution.